# Oversampled polyphase filter banks

Tags: filters, sampling, dft, filter-bank

i would a confirm of this: with polyphase structure is possible only design a filter bank with a INTEGER oversampling ratio? For non-integer i've seen the weighted overlap-add metod, is right?

thanks
S.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 1D uniform $M$-channel [multirate filter bank (FB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bank#Multirate_Filter_Bank), and $N$ is the decimation ($M \ge N$),  [rational oversampling ratios](http://image.unb.br/queiroz/papers/icassp01rvb.pdf)  ($M/N$) are indeed possible (see Fig. 2), or from Figure 1 in [Optimization of Synthesis Oversampled Complex Filter Banks](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.3654.pdf), J. Gautier *et al.*, IEEE Trans. Signal Processing, 2009 ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2009.2023947)), which provides optimized synthesis FB with any ratio (like $7/4$).

More precisely: for an analysis filter bank, you can choose any decimation you want. But you may loose information, and the invertibility of the analysis/synthesis system. In a  lot of practical applications (for instance in speech processing), integer oversampling ratios are quite common, by choosing $N = M/k$, for instance $k=M/2$ or $k=M/4$. Such choices make the  computations and some calculations much simpler: for instance, an inverse synthesis filter bank may take a closed form, related to the  analysis window for DFT FBs.

However with redundancy, there are an infinity of inverses, and polyphase formulations help finding synthesis FBs.

A set of useful books (to me):

- [Subband compression of images: principles and examples](https://www.elsevier.com/books/subband-compression-of-images-principles-and-examples/ramstad/978-0-444-89431-1), T. Ramstad et al., 1995
- [Wavelets and Subband Coding](http://waveletsandsubbandcoding.org/Repository/VetterliKovacevic95_Manuscript.pdf), M. Vetterli et al., 1995
- [Wavelets and filte banks](http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/books/wfb.html), G. Strang et al., 1996

Comment: Thanks! It's awesome paper! I don't Know why the book of Crochiere "Multirate Digital Signal Processing" says only integer oversampling ratio..

Comment: 1st edition, page 325 where talks about comparision between polyphase and wola.

Comment: I understand the chapter as "In this section [...] the polyphase structure is limited **primarily** to the critically sampled case where $M = K$ or to cases when $MI = K$, where $I$ is an integer". Sooner, they say that "This realization is most easily seen for the case of critically sampled filter banks where $M = K$. Designs for other choices of $M$ (or $K$) are not as straightforward as the critically sampled case". Primarily is important here. It does not mean it is impossible

Comment: Ok i didn't understand well. Thanks. I have another doubt .(, having M channels, N decimation factor and polyphase structure. In all documents, the analysis polyphase matrix is MxN. But Why?  If the prototype filter H0 has length L, the matrix should have M x L/M, or not? Namely, for me each row of this matrix represents one polyphase component of length L/M. Where do i wrong?

Comment: Polyphase behave like a subsampling of filter coefficients by $N$. So you have the  subsequences $0, N, 2N...$,  $1, N+1, 2N+1...$ up to $N-1,2N-1, ...$, hence $(N-1)-0+1$ polyphase component per filter. The  polyphase size does not depend on the  filter size, which is one of its main advantages.

Comment: I have added a few book that I found interesting on FBs and polyphase